# How to load a tmlanguage file into SubLime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have downloaded a typescript.tmlanguage so that I can have typescript syntax highlighting in the Sublime Text 2 editor.
How do I load this file in the editor?
(I have searched the editor's manual but there is no clear answer on this one)
Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should create `Typescript` directory in your `Packages` directory and put `typescript.tmLanguage` in it.

Packages directory can be found with menu `Preferences/Browse Packages...`.