# Add .ts language files to Sublime Text to support additional syntax coloring

Tags: sublimetext2, typescript

I'm trying to add Typescript syntax highlighting support, which is [provided](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/10/01/sublime-text-vi-emacs-typescript-enabled.aspx) by MSFT. However, I don't know what to do with that downloaded .zip to make Sublime recognize `.ts` files. I tried adding it to `Installed Packages/Typescript`, or just `Installed Packages`, but that hasn't worked. (I also tried extracting the `.tmlanguage` file and putting that in `Installed Packages/Typescript`.

What is the right way to do this? (I'm on Mac OS X 10.8 with Sublime text 2.0.1.)

Comment: Dropping the zip file contents in any folder under Installed Packages should be enough.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762736/how-to-load-a-tmlanguage-file-into-sublime-text-2

Comment: Rosarch did [Claudijo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12790025/61654) not do the trick for you?

Comment: Can you updated the link to the zip file? This is not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

To add TypeScript syntax highlighting support to Sublime Text on Mac:

1. Unzip the downloaded file. It contains a file named typescript.tmlanguage
2. Create a subfolder in your sublime Package folder called TypeScript. (The path to the Packages folder for Sublime Text 2 on Mac is:
    `/Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages)`
3. Drop typescript.tmlanguage into your newly created TypeScript folder.

Comment: thanks, this worked and was trying to add smalltalk syntax to sublime 3

Answer (score 9):

For me none of these ways actually worked as they should have.

Instead I had to hit (On a Mac and using Sublime Text 2) **Cmd+Shift+P** and then type **Package Control:Install Package** and then hit enter. You may see it load in the bottom left.

From there is was a matter of searching for the script (in my case TypeScript), selecting it and hitting enter.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

If you go to the [Sublime Text](http://docs.sublimetext.info) website, they have instructions there. To make it work in Windows you have to create the Typescript folder at:

> C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\TypeScript

and copy the typescript.tmlanguage file inside that folder. Claudijo provides an e[quivalent answer for Mac OS X users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12790025/61654).

Comment: Searching on `Typescript` on the Sublime Text website link you provided does not bring up anything on `Typescript`